# Apache processes are not ending

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, process

I have KeepAlive on with 15 second timeout enabled. But processes are not ending. And it causes big number of apache processes which ends with server freeze. The only option is to hard reset server.

Why this happens? How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely [MaxClients](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients) is too high. Depending on your MPM, too many clients causes the process count problems you see.